# Problems with web scraping the UFC site for fighter information

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to build an MMA blog/stats website and to do so, I am scraping the UFC site for the information of each athlete. I am using Beautiful Soup and Python.

So far, I have managed to scrape an athlete's name, however, when I loop through, it only repeats the first athlete's name instead of displaying the next athlete and so on.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')



for fighter in soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'l-flex__item'}):
    # nickname = fighter.span.text
    name = soup.find('span', class_='c-listing-athlete__name').text
    record = soup.find('span', class_='c-listing-athlete__record').text
    print(name, end='')
```

This is the output in my terminal:
[What happens when I print my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU366.png)

I would appreciate if anyone could point out any mistakes I have made in the logic of the for loop. Thank you!

Comment: You're not using `fighter` anywhere in the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot to use it in the loop itself smh haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through `<li>` which is corrent, but inside the loop you refer to the whole url (`soup`). You need to use your `fighter` variable from the loop. Since there are more `<li>` items which got no text, you can work with `try` and `except`.

```
for fighter in soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'l-flex__item'}):
    # nickname = fighter.span.text
    try: 
        name = fighter.find('span', class_='c-listing-athlete__name').text
    except: 
        pass
    try:
        record = fighter.find('span', class_='c-listing-athlete__record').text
    except:
        pass
    print(f'Name:{name.strip()}, record:{record}')
```

**output**

```
Name:Shamil Abdurakhimov, record:20-5-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Ricardo Abreu, record:5-1-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Klidson Abreu, record:15-5-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Juan Adams, record:5-3-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Zarrukh Adashev, record:0-1-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Israel Adesanya, record:19-0-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Mariya Agapova, record:1-0-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Jessica Aguilar, record:20-8-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Kevin Aguilar, record:17-4-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Christian Aguilera, record:1-0-0 (W-L-D)
Name:Omari Akhmedov, record:20-4-1 (W-L-D)
Name:Omari Akhmedov, record:20-4-1 (W-L-D)
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a legend. Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense! I completely forgot about printing the value that I am using in the loop haha. I'm new to Python which is why my knowledge is a bit limited.